# How to synatx a piecewise where x=0 is undefined?

Tags: piecewise

How to write the synatx for a piecewise where x=0 is undefined in the domain of the function, and according to the below conditions ?

y := Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < Pi}, {-1, -Pi < x < 0}}]

Comment: is doesn't generate the auto plot for the piecewise.

Comment: How I can plot the above piecewise?

Answer (score 1):

From help

[image]

Compare

```
y[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < Pi}, {-1, -Pi < x < 0}}];
Plot[y[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

To make it undefined, one way is to do this

```
y[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, 0 < x < Pi}, {-1, -Pi < x < 0}}, Nothing];
Plot[y[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

So any $x$ not in conditions will have `Nothing` as its value instead of zero.